# The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.v4.content' that cannot be safely rewritten. for androidx

Tags: android, butterknife, androidx, android-jetifier

I upgraded my `android studio to 3.4 canary` and now I cannot successfully build anymore due to the following error:

```
The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.v4.content' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.
```

More details:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Failed to transform '.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/com.jakewharton/butterknife-compiler/9.0.0-SNAPSHOT/732f93940c74cf32a7c5ddcc5ef66e53be052352/butterknife-compiler-9.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar' using Jetifier. Reason: The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.v4.content' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.. (Run with --stacktrace for more details.)
```

Clearly, its something to do with `Butterknife, androidx and Jetifier`

Do anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: tried this: [this](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119135578#comment5) but no luck

Comment: What was the regular expression you tried to add to the blacklist?

Comment: The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.v4.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.

I am receiving above error, when i am trying to create signed apk with minifyenabled and shrinkresources set to true. I am able to run application in emulator or device otherwise. How to resolve this issue?

Comment: Nice question! Very Helpful, Thanks

Answer (score 204, accepted):

**New correct answer:**

Butterknife 10.0.0 added support for AndroidX.

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
}
```

---

**Old answer for Butterknife < 10.0.0:**

Try blacklisting butterknife from the jetifier:

```
gradle.properties file:

android.jetifier.blacklist = butterknife.*\\.jar
```

You need to be on the 3.3.0-rc1 of the AGP and the 1.3.0 version of the Kotlin Gradle plugin:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        ...
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.0-rc01'
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:1.3.0"
        classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-rc2'
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you don't add android.jetifier.blacklist = butterknife.*\\.jar because I tested it didn't work. You only add classpath 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-gradle-plugin:9.0.0-rc2' then it will working when debug and export file apk without a problem.

Comment: More info can be found here https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/119135578#comment5

Comment: This answer is correct, but have a look at: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54345816/371749 update butterknife to 10, also resolves this issue in a better way.

Comment: This solution works fine for debug build but I am not able to create signed release APK.

The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.v4.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.

Answer (score 63):

Add the last version of the butterknive dependency you can check it here if it changes (https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife). 
It supports androidX. Then go to your app build graddle and replace the old version with the following:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 28):

For androidx simply upgrade your dependencies to version '10.0.0'

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
}
```

Look for documentation [here](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife)

Comment: My Click edit text box gives null pointer. it is not initialize.

Answer (score 20):

Upgrade ButterKnife to latest version and make sure to add these into your build.gradle(app):

```
android {
...
compileOptions {
    sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
}
}
```

Comment: best answer, after the upgeade I've searched this solution for --> Error: Static interface methods are only supported starting with Android N (--min-api 24): void butterknife.Unbinder.lambda$static$0()

Comment: love you man you made it ... i wasted half the day searching then this answer comes.

Answer (score 10):

My project doesn't use butterknife, but I had the same error "The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.v4.widget' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx
"
This what I did to solve it: Update your parceler version

**gradle build file**

Replace:

```
annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.6'
implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.6'
```

With:

```
  annotationProcessor 'org.parceler:parceler:1.1.13'
  implementation 'org.parceler:parceler-api:1.1.13'
```

[image: gradle file code]
[image: gradle file view]

Answer (score 3):

Which version if Butterknife you use? Latest version 9.0.0-rc2 supports androidx.

UPD: There is closed issue on butterknife's [github repo](https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/issues/1395). [Temporary workaround](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/118658603#comment5)

Add android.jetifier.blacklist=butterknife-compiler to your gradle.properties file.

Comment: I'm on 9.0.0-rc2 and I'm getting the exact same error

Answer (score 2):

Using the latest version of Butterknife resolved the issue. Use >= 9.0.0-rc2 (Butterknife Version) to support androidX.
For the latest release check the link - https://github.com/JakeWharton/butterknife/releases

Answer (score 2):

Change

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">`

to

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.DarkActionBar">`

or other Material Themes.
Got this error after starting New Project with "No Activity" in Android Studio 4.0.1

Answer (score 1):

update butterknife + invalidate cache and restart + sync gradle
if buterknife not used just clear cache and restart

Answer (score 0):

For my old project I was facing the same issue, tried all options but not worked,
only this change works for me:

Do following changes in **gradle.properties** file

```
android.useAndroidX=false
android.enableJetifier=false
```