# How to fix 'android.support.v4.content' in androidx?

Tags: android, android-studio, androidx

I migrated my  android old project to androidx to use the updated library and fix the dependencies. But it still causing below issues. And app is not get compiled. How I can resolve this issues? Is there any idea?

```
The given artifact contains a string literal with a package reference 'android.support.v4.content' that cannot be safely rewritten. Libraries using reflection such as annotation processors need to be updated manually to add support for androidx.
```

Comment: please share file build.gradle

Comment: @JavadDehban https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdh6cnnmzy98yn2/Gradle.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 2):

Butterknife 10.0.0 added support for AndroidX. changing the butterknife dependency version solved it for me

```
dependencies {
    implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.0.0'
    annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.0.0'
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the following settings:

```
  implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:10.2.1'
  annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:10.2.1'
```

Comment: Dehban, I tried it still causing the same issues even I tries its other versions as well. Can you please advise what is other root of cause?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53484988/the-given-artifact-contains-a-string-literal-with-a-package-reference-android-s I followed this link as well. But seems not get work.

Comment: Dehban, can you please advise?

Comment: Javad this is the build.gradle code
https://www.dropbox.com/s/rdh6cnnmzy98yn2/Gradle.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 0):

Follow these Steps.

- first of all migrate to AndroidX by updating your project use this  version of the support library: version 28.0.0.
- Refactor > Migrate to AndroidX from the menu bar.
- The refactor command makes use of two flags. By default, both of them are set to true in your gradle.properties file:
  android.useAndroidX=true
- The Android plugin uses the appropriate AndroidX library instead of a
  Support Library. android.enableJetifier=true
  The Android plugin
  automatically migrates existing third-party libraries to use AndroidX
  by rewriting their binaries.

Comment: Samer I followed the same steps twice, it still causing same issue. Can you please advise what is the other root cause in this?

Comment: Be sure to use those two lines  **android.useAndroidX=true** and **android.enableJetifier=true**   in gradle.properties

Comment: Samer both line are set to true in gradle.properties.

Comment: before it should be like that **implementation ‘com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0’
**   after migration should be **implementation ‘androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2’** check this also if the error stills send me your project and I will solve it to you.

Comment: Samer it support upto  implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0' but not implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'. It says new version is 1.1.0 is available. Can you please confirm what is the other library required for this?

Answer (score -1):

Please try using the following settings:

implementation 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:(insert latest version)'

annotationProcessor 'com.jakewharton:butterknife-compiler:(insert latest version)'

Comment: Welcome on SO! This is not really a new answer. If you think that mentioning “the latest version”, instead of 10.0.0, is worthwile, you should submit an edit to Paul’s or Javad’s answer (click on “Improve this answer” under the one you want to edit).